# Getting Empty Rows in Google Analytics Data API

Tags: php, json, api, analytics

Having difficulty getting empty rows from the Analytics Data API (GA4) BETA. I'm pulling simple traffic by date array but any dates that have zero traffic are not returned - I would prefer it to give me the date and zero.

I believe there should be a KEEPEMPTYROWS parameter but this doesn't seem to work - it took me so long to get the ORDERBY working that I thought I'd check here first to see if anyone else has got this working lol. I know I can fill in the missing dates using PHP code but I'd prefer to get it from the query. Here's the PHP for my JSON query:

```
$response = $client->runReport([
'property' => 'properties/' . $_SESSION["gaid"],
'dateRanges' => [
    new DateRange([
        'start_date' => $mstartdate,
        'end_date' => $menddate,
    ]),
],
'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
    [
        'name' => 'date',
    ]
),
],
'metrics' => [new Metric(
    [
        'name' => 'activeUsers',
        'name' => 'sessions',
    ]
)
],
'orderBys' => [
    new OrderBy([
        'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
            'dimension_name' => 'date',
            'order_type' => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::ALPHANUMERIC
        ]),
        'desc' => false,
    ])],
    'keepEmptyRows'=>"1"
```

]);

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try as I might, I couldn't get this working, so I wrote some PHP code to feed the data into an array and then add the missing dates and re-sort it. Not ideal but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for an answer, the option is called "keepEmptyRows":

```
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(['credentials' => ...]);
$response = $client->runReport([
    ...
    'keepEmptyRows' => true,
]);
```

Source:
https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data/blob/master/src/V1beta/RunReportRequest.php#L642

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected.

I was asking for a 7 day report, expecting each 7 rows, each containing 0s (previously UA was working like that).
Instead I got single row with 0s.

This problem is also mentioned here:
https://github.com/google/site-kit-wp/issues/6623

In the end, I ended up pre-filling the array with the default data before applying changes that come from GA.